# How do I download a file from an HTTPS server within a wxWidgets C++ App?

Tags: ssl, https, wxwidgets

I am trying to download a csv file from an HTTPS server using wxWidgets in MS Visual C++.  I was doing it from an HTTP server but that is no longer an option.  I found a place to down load from an HTTPS server. wxWidgets does not support HTTPS.  I downloaded wxCurl but that looks like I need OpenSSL and Boost as well. 
Way more overkill than what I need or at least what I want to deal with. I am a retire embedded real-time programmer and my only network experience is the very lowest level sockets interface.

I am looking for a simple option for handing my URL to a function and getting a file stream I can read programmatically. How should I be phrasing my question for searching on-line?  It seems that everything I find is way out of date or way over my head.

I am capable of rebuilding libraries but not debugging their internals (or at least not interested in it).  What should I be looking for?  Are there some code snippets some where or a straight forward library?

Eddie

It looks like both libcurl and rest depend on boost and ssl.  wxCurl is based on libcurl but wxCurl is not currently maintained, while libcurl is.  I will try the libcurl and see how many external dependencies it has.  I'm still open to a simpler answer.

Comment: You could use libcurl directly instead of wxCurl. libcurl does not need OpenSSL on Windows, and definitely doesn't need boost.

Answer (score 0):

[C++ REST SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) provides a simple way to download files asynchronously and also has quite a lot of other useful functionality.